# KDE taskbar widget showing up in the middle of my screen

Tags: linux, desktop, kde, opensuse, widgets

Suddenly, my widgets seem to be showing up in the middle of my screen. My calendar and everything else. Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I've restarted my computer several times and restarted X a couple times as well. Advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also try switching window managers to something more lightweight; like **[dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/)**.

> dwm is a dynamic window manager for X. It manages windows in tiled, monocle and floating layouts. All of the layouts can be applied dynamically, optimising the environment for the application in use and the task performed.
>
> In tiled layout windows are managed in a master and stacking area. The master area contains the window which currently needs most attention, whereas the stacking area contains all other windows. In monocle layout all windows are maximised to the screen size. In floating layout windows can be resized and moved freely. Dialog windows are always managed floating, regardless of the layout applied.
>
> Windows are grouped by tags. Each window can be tagged with one or multiple tags. Selecting certain tags displays all windows with these tags.
>
> Each screen contains a small status bar which displays all available tags, the layout, the number of visible windows, the title of the focused window, and the text read from the root window name property, if the screen is focused. A floating window is indicated with an empty square and a maximised floating window is indicated with a filled square before the windows title. The selected tags are indicated with a different color. The tags of the focused window are indicated with a filled square in the top left corner. The tags which are applied to one or more windows are indicated with an empty square in the top left corner.
>
> dwm draws a small customizable border around windows to indicate the focus state.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Not just because of this bug, but I do like dwm a lot.

Comment: @MaxMackie, would you mind adding some more details to the answer, as to why you ended up doing this?

Comment: @Ivo, I was finding KDE to be very slow (dolphin took a long time to index my HDDs) and other visual bugs. I've always seen `dwm` used in nice arch setups so I decided to give it a try. I never was able to fix my KDE bug, but @user81997 provided an alternative I was already using :)

Answer (score 0):

Just click and hold the title bar of the popup widget with your mouse and drag it to the location you would like it to appear.  The next time you click on the clock, device notifier, etc. it will appear in the location you dragged it to.

(I believe the ability to move these was added in KDE 4.7 and there's a bug that results in it not knowing where to put them at first and shoving them in the middle of the screen.  I recall having to move mine from the center of the screen as well.)

Comment: I should have mentioned I already tried this. Once I drag it back, it disappears fine but clicking again brings it right back in the middle.

Comment: @MaxMackie:  That's odd, it persisted for me.  (And I was running KDE 4.7RC1 at the time!)  In that case I'd strongly suggest you [file a bug against Plasma with openSUSE](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Submitting_bug_reports).  You can tell them it persists just fine on Fedora 15 with KDE4.7 from `kde-unstable` so the problem is most likely somewhere on their end.